# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache') discord bot trying to read input from a chatroom

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to create a bot in discord that allows 2 captains two alternate picking teams until there are teams of 4 on each side. (1 captain, and 3 others). The captain would be picked randomly once 8 members signify; they are ready.

`

```
class MessageCreateAction extends Action {
  handle(data) {
    const client = this.client;
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(data.channel_id);
    if (channel) {
      const existing = channel.messages.cache.get(data.id);
      if (existing) return { message: existing };
      const message = channel.messages.add(data);
      const user = message.author;
      let member = message.member;
      channel.lastMessageID = data.id;
      if (user) {
        user.lastMessageID = data.id;
        user.lastMessageChannelID = channel.id;
      }
      if (member) {
        member.lastMessageID = data.id;
        member.lastMessageChannelID = channel.id;
      }

      /**
       * Emitted whenever a message is created.
       * @event Client#message
       * @param {Message} message The created message
       */
      client.emit(Events.MESSAGE_CREATE, message);
      return { message };
    }

    return {};
  }
}
```

`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to fetch the guild where the channel is in, after that you can get the channel and message.

You can also see this post made by another user with the same error has you https://stackoverflow.com/a/66873076/15256312

you need to use **ASYNCHRONOUS** (async) to use **await**

```
const client = this.client;
const guild = client.guilds.cache.fetch(data.guild_id);
const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(data.channel_id);
if (channel) {
    const existing = await channel.messages.fetch(data.id);
    //...
}
```